# conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when reading from file

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know this question has been posted on stackoverflow in different forms but I didn't manage to solve my problem. I am trying to insert into an sql server database data read from a text file. I have inserted previously data into the database in the format '2014-02-02' so I don't think it's from here. My text file looks like this :

```
1213 3 2013-01-03 2013-03-03
1263 2 2014-01-01 2014-01-10
```

and my code is:

```
        private void importComandăToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            string cale = Application.StartupPath;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                cale = ofd.FileName;
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(cale);
                string linie = null;
                while ((linie = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                        string comanda = sr.ReadLine();
                        string[] vcmd = comanda.Split(' ');

                        foreach (string cmd in vcmd)
                        {
                             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
    "database=erp; " +
    "connection timeout=30");
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd1.CommandText = "Insert into [erp].[dbo].[Comenzi] values("+Int32.Parse(cmd[0].ToString())+","+Int32.Parse(cmd[1].ToString())+",'"+cmd[2].ToString()+"','"+cmd[3].ToString()+"');";
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                        }

                    }
                MessageBox.Show("Comanda inserată");

                }

            else
                MessageBox.Show("Inserare eșuată");
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why not parse the data and do your string to datetime conversion in c# and then pass a correct sqlparameter to your insert statement?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem are the two date in your file. If they are expressed in the format accepted by your locale settings then a conversion could be enough. However your code that tries to update the database has many errors.

I have tried to fix them.

- First. use the using statement to correctly close the connection when
  you have done
- Second. use a parameterized query to pass data to your database.
  String concatenation is prone to error for bad parsing and open to
  sql injection hacks.
- Third. open the connection just before entering the loop and create
  the command with its parameters with some dummy values. Inside the
  loop change the value of the parameters to the actual value and
  execute the query
- Fourth. The splitting of the string produces an array and you need to
  use the FOUR elements of the array not inexistant elements of the
  `cmd` single string variable
- Fifth. You read the line two times for each loop. Unless you have a
  blank row every line of data then you should remove the ReadLine
  inside the loop

.

```
 private void importComandăToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string cale = Application.StartupPath;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        cale = ofd.FileName;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(cale);
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                                 "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                 "database=erp; " +
                                 "connection timeout=30"))
        using(SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into [erp].[dbo].[Comenzi] values 
                                                @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4", conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 0);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", 0);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", DateTime.MinValue);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", DateTime.MinValue);
            string comanda = null;
            while ((comanda = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] vcmd = comanda.Split(' ');
                cmd1.Parameters["@p1"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(vcmd[0]));
                cmd1.Parameters["@p2"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(vcmd[1]));
                cmd1.Parameters["@p3"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(vcmd[2]));
                cmd1.Parameters["@p4"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(vcmd[3]));
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why it is necessary to add default values? Also do we have to cast strings into respective data types while adding values to parameter?

Comment: In the example above the parameters are created once with the AddWithValue when we are outside the loop. AddWithValue requires a value but at that point I don't have any value, so I just set them with dummy values. You could use a more verbose way to create parameters with the Add method but there is no point in to do so in this case.

Comment: Parameters have a datatype that should match the datatype of the fields in the database. Again I have used AddWithValue, so the datatype for the parameter is inferred by the datatype of the value passed for the creation. I suppose that the datatable has two integer columns and two datetime columns so I have used a matching parameter for these column to avoid possible conversion errors. Of course if the assumption in incorrect then we need to change this code

Comment: I have changed my answer according to your approach. Thank  you.

Answer (score 0):

remove the foreach.

```
private void importComandaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            string cale = Application.StartupPath;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                cale = ofd.FileName;
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(cale);
                string linie = null;
                while ((linie = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                        string comanda = sr.ReadLine();
                        string[] vcmd = comanda.Split(' ');

                        //foreach (string cmd in vcmd)
                        //{
                             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
    "database=erp; " +
    "connection timeout=30");
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd1.CommandText = "Insert into [erp].[dbo].[Comenzi] values("+vcmd[0]+","+vcmd[1]+",'"+vcmd[2]+"','"+vcmd[3]+"');";
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                        //}

                    }
                MessageBox.Show("Comanda inserata");

                }

            else
                MessageBox.Show("Inserare e?uata");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If cmd is a string, cmd[0] is going to give you the first character in the string. I don't think that's what you want. You probably meant vcmd[0] which means you don't need the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer clearly explains all issues exists in your code.

When you do this:

```
 string[] vcmd = comanda.Split(' ');
```

You get array of line just like this `string[] array`

```
 string[] vcmd = {"1213", "3", "2013-01-03", "2013-03-03" };
```

Below loop on `string[]` would give you each string in `cmd` variable:

```
 foreach (string cmd in vcmd)
 {
     //here cmd values on each iteration

     // first iteration = "1213"
     // second iteration = "3"
     // third iteration = "2013-01-03"
     // fourth iteration = "2013-03-03"
  }
```

**Better approach can be**:

1. Read all lines of files in one go.
2. Create `SqlConnection` at the beginning of method.
3. Use `SqlCommand Parameters`.
4. Use `using` statement.

**Example (not tested)**:

```
private void importComandăToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connstring = @"server=localhost; 
                         Trusted_Connection=yes; 
                         database=erp; connection timeout=30";

   string cale = GetFileName();

   if(cale != string.Empty)
   {
      IEnumerable<string> arrLines = File.ReadLines(cale);
      string sql = @"Insert into [erp].[dbo].[Comenzi] values 
                                            (@P1, @P2, @P3, @P4)";
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
      {
          conn.Open();
          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
          {
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", 0);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", 0);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P3", DateTime.MinValue);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P4", DateTime.MinValue);

              foreach (string sLine in arrLines)
              {
                 string[] vcmd = sLine.Split(' ');
                 cmd.Parameters["@P1"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(vcmd[0]);
                 cmd.Parameters["@P2"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(vcmd[1]);
                 cmd.Parameters["@P3"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(vcmd[2]);
                 cmd.Parameters["@P4"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(vcmd[3]);
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
          }
       }
       //check can be added based on int returned by ExecuteNonQuery
       MessageBox.Show("Comanda inserată");
    }                
}

//method to show open file dialog return filename or empty
private string GetFileName()
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         return ofd.FileName;
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Inserare eșuată");
         return string.Empty;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.It works. it has a few syntax errors such as: you have to add parenthesis in the insert command  `string sql = @"Insert into [erp].[dbo].[Comenzi] values (@P1, @P2, @P3, @P4)";` and when adding the parameters remove one of the parenthesis so it would be like `cmd.Parameters["@P1"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(vcmd[0]);`

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed both syntax issues.